# ListView with columns and rows Android

Tags: android, listview, gridview

I'm developing an Android app and in one screen layout I need to have a gridview with header, but there isn't any header for gridview. So I saw in instagram profile that they use listview like a gridview, but I couldn't find anything about it, so if somebody knows an alternative way to do this kind of thing, I would appreciate.

I want something like this:
[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found a solution, it's make a list with an adapter with multiple items, so we can make a "gridview" with a list.

Hope this help somebody in the future.

In the link bellow you can download from git
https://github.com/umano/MultiItemRowListAdapter

Answer (score 1):

Try following code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

   <GridView
       android:id="@+id/gridViewCustom"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:layout_margin="4dp"
       android:columnWidth="80dp"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:numColumns="auto_fit"
       android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
   </GridView>

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="50dp"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:text="THIS IS THE HEADER"
       android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And in your Activity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.grid);

        final TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        GridView grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridViewCustom);
        grid.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                    int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                if(firstVisibleItem == 0)//or it is maybe 1 I'm not sure. It means you are at the top of the gridview
                    txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                else
                    txt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't work for what I need, I need the header and listview scroll together. Thanks for your try

Comment: I don't want to disappear with the header, only scroll it